# Navigation View menu crashing when trying to get menu item - Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I'm trying to make an item invisible from the `Activity` main drawer in a navigation drawer project. However, at the moment that I try to access to the menu to get the item and set it invisible, the app crashes.

Here's my code:

```
NavigationView nav_draw = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_draw);
Menu menu = nav_draw.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_item_1).setVisible(false);
```

I don't know what is happening. I'm trying to do this in a `SettingsActivity`, that extends `PreferenceActivity`.

Here's the `nav_header_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@color/PaletteSecondary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:text="Social Slide"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_s_white"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the `activity_main_drawer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inicio"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="Inicio"
            android:visible="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_fb"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_fb"
            android:title="Facebook" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_twitter"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter"
            android:title="Twitter" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_instagram"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_insta"
            android:title="Instagram" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tumblr"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_tumblr"
            android:title="Tumblr" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Extras">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Comparte" />
            <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_mas"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_apps_black"
            android:title="Descarga otras Apps" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: The id of the navigation drawer and the menu are correct in the proyect, but the function wont work, and just retrieving the menu from the navigation view crashes the proyect.

Comment: Please share the logcat for the crash log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this method in onCreate:

```
hideNavigationItem();

private void hideNavigationItem() {
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_draw);  
        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_inicio).setVisible(false);
    }
```